# saving the data into postgres through php

Tags: php, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.2

I have attached the code below.It is the form to accept the values from user interface and i want to save the result in postgresql database but my interface is working fine but not the values in the database are not inserted.

```
 <?php
 include("connection.php");
 error_reporting(0);
   ?>

 <html>
 <head>
 <title>TESTING INTERFACE</TITLE>

 </head>
 <body>
 <BR>
 TESTING INTERFACE
 <BR>
 <form action ="" method="GET">

   Year <input type="text" name ="Year" value =""/><br><br>
  GDP<input type="text" name ="GDP" value =""/><br><br>
  Gross Indirect Tax <input type="text" name ="Gross_Indirect_Tax" value 
  =""/><br><br>
  CE Revenue<input type="text" name =" CE_Revenue" value =""/><br><br>
  CE Revenue percentage<input type="text" name ="CE_REvenue_Percentage" 
  value =""/><br><br>
  <input type ="submit" name="" value ="submit"/>

  </form>

  <?php
   $yr = $_GET['Year'];
   $gs = $_GET['GDP'];
    $rs1 = $_GET['Gross_Indirect_Tax'];
   $rs2 = $_GET['CE_Revenue'];
   $rs3 = $_GET['CE_REvenue_Percentage'];


 echo $yr;
  echo $gs;
 echo $rs1;
echo $rs2;
echo $rs3;

//echo "$_POST[Year]";
 $query = "INSERT INTO indirecttax 
(Year,GDP,Gross_Indirect_Tax,CE_Revenue,CE_REvenue_Percentage) 
VALUES($yr,$gs,$rs1,$rs2,$rs3)" ;
$x = pg_query($query);
//$qw = pg_query (INSERT INTO indirecttax 
(Year,GDP,Gross_Indirect_Tax,CE_Revenue,CE_REvenue_Percentage) 
 VALUES($yr,$gs,$rs1,$rs2,$rs3)) ;
//$query = "INSERT INTO Criteria_Parameters 
(CriteriaID,DomainID,Criteria_Name,Upper_Limit,Lower_Limit,Range,Unit) 
VALUES 


/*
 $data = pg_query($conn,$qw);

 if($data)
 {
 echo "data inserted into database";

 }
 else
 {
  echo "sorry";
  }
 */
  ?>
  </body>
  </html>
```

my connection.php file is working fine.
My insert statement is not giving the results

Comment: please post the code which does the work of inserting data into your database; i hope you have that, and are not wishing for the values to magically put themselves into the datastore.

Comment: If you're trying to debug something **why** switch off error reporting?

Comment: `/*
 $data = pg_query($conn,$qw);... */` why did you comment that out? That won't run.

Comment: `//$qw = pg_query (INSERT INTO indirecttax 
(Year,GDP,Gross_Indirect_Tax,CE_Revenue,CE_REvenue_Percentage)` same for that.

Comment: I'm voting this one as a typo based question.

Comment: `error_reporting(0);` that did **not** help you.

Comment: after uncommenting to is did not worked

Answer (score -1):

It seems you forgot to pass the connection to `pg_query`.

Try this:

```
pg_query($conn, $query);
```

where `$conn` is the object returned by your call to `pg_pconnect`

Comment: They did, in a way. Look at their code again and very carefully, as well as the comments I left under their post.

Comment: I tried this too...it is uncommented in my code ,issue is values are not inserting in database

Comment: @nitisethi try removing `error_reporting(0);` end tell me if there is any error being displayed